# Visual Studio hide tabs (tab well) in editor

Tags: visual-studio

I'm sure this feature used to be available, but I can't seem to find it anymore. You used to be able to open documents in the editor with no tab. In other words you relied only on keyboard to navigate between open documents. Can someone help please?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?

Comment: [Now there is a way to do that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39080664/is-there-a-way-to-remove-tab-well/39955791#39955791)

Answer (score -2):

Go to menu Edit - Advanced - uncheck View White Space.

Comment: This is not correct whatsoever. This edits the White Space visual in the Editor, not what the question is asking about tabs.