# Is there a way to remove tab well?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Is there a way to hide this tab bar?

[image]

*P.S. Not sure is this question belongs to stackoverflow*

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Since you already identified an [exact duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33252098/205233), why did you post this?

Comment: @Filburt it was asked a year ago and received zero answers. What should I do in such cases?

Comment: Offer a bounty - in any case don't post known duplicates. No we are in the unhappy situation of a duplicate with an answer that doesn't answer the problem.

Comment: @NoelC Why was my suggestion to avoid asking a duplicate not constructive? I did not call names or anything the like. Advocating asking duplicates because "I want MY answer" does not add any value to this site. And in what way this question is more precise - other than adding a screenshot?

Comment: @NoelC I suggest you're doing some duty on the duplicate/off-topic queues to get a new perspective of unhappiness about the quality of the content of this site. This is not some personal pet peeve but agreed standards of this community.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I've done this myself by writing a VS extension. Also switched Title bar and Menu bar to auto-hide. Now at last my VS has a minimalistic view

[image]

[GitHub](https://github.com/poma/MinimalisticView)

[VS gallery](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3cdaac43-56d3-4d84-ba46-cf880b4d013d)

Comment: ...this doesn't provide an answer to anyone else, hence my downvote.

Comment: Oh I forgot to link it. Fixed

Comment: Since links can decay, can you add the code here and instructions on how to use?

Comment: GitHub links are pretty durable. I've had to decompile Visual Studio and use its internal libraries to create a XAML style that overrides default panels behavior. Then I've just merged my styles to `Application.Current.Resources`. My extension is full of dirty tricks but it does its job.

Comment: Ah, okay - I've never used VisualStudio so I'm unsure on how the extension was made, though it's SO etiquette, but okay `:)`

Comment: Extension is not available for vs2022

Comment: Unfortunately GitHub banned my account for contributing to "undesirable" project

Answer (score 1):

Clearly it's an overkill, but you can install my [Tabs Studio](https://tabsstudio.com/) extension and style it to hide tabs:

```
<Style TargetType="TabsStudio:Tabs" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultTabsStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
</Style>
```