# Hide/Remove tabs manager in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Like in a title, how can I totally remove tabs, to see only code view?

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39080664/is-there-a-way-to-remove-tab-well

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what your ultimate goal is.

If you want to show **the code only**, you can use *View -> Full Screen* to full screen your code.

Comment: F11 is `Debug` > `Step Into` by [default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2017).  You must be using non-default keybindings, or an extension.

Comment: The *default* keybinding for full screen view seems to be `shift` + `alt` + `enter`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot without the help of an addon that does that.
 As a workaround you can double click the tabs to maximized it.